# How do I keep my scene layout from getting messed up when resizing my windows?

Tags: unity

Whenever my *scene* window gets resized the layout gets messed up. This included when I move or resize other views in my workflow in such a way that it changes the size of the scene window (see screenshots). This makes Unity nearly unusable. How do I prevent this nonsense?

Correct scene layout:

[image: Correct Scene Layout]

Messed up scene layout:

[image: Messed Up Scene Layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The camera has several layers of background to it. I had to go to each one and click the "enable the constrained proportions" button.